# Landau-Peierls Substitution in Haldane Model

Tags: solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, graphene

In his [1988 paper "Model for a quantum Hall effect without Landau levels: Condensed-matter realization of the parity anomaly" [1]](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.2015), Haldane performs a Landau-Peierls Substitution $\hbar\delta\mathbf{k}\rightarrow\mathbf{\Pi}$.

The paper defines $\mathbf\Pi$ as

> $\mathbf{\Pi}=\left(\Pi^x, \Pi^y\right)$ is the
>   dynamical momentum with components satisfying the
>   commutation relation $\left[\Pi^x,\Pi^y\right] =i\hbar eB_0$.

- What is this dynamical momentum and how can it be understood?
- All definitions of the Peierls substitution I found take the form $t\rightarrow t e^{i\frac{e}{\hbar}\int\mathbf{A} d\mathbf{r}}$, how does this relate to the substitution performed by Haldane?
- How does this substitution result in (2): $\mathbf{H}_\alpha=c\left(\Pi_\alpha^1\mathbf\sigma^2-\Pi_\alpha^2\mathbf\sigma^1\right)+m_\alpha c^2 \mathbf\sigma^3$?

---

[1](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.2015) Haldane, F. Duncan M. "Model for a quantum Hall effect without Landau levels: Condensed-matter realization of the" parity anomaly"." Physical Review Letters 61.18 (1988): 2015.

Comment: Without reading the paper, this is the standard minimal substitution, also called the Weyl substitution, of gauge theory. According to this rule, you substitute the classical momentum by a quantum covariant derivative $p\rightarrow p+A\rightarrow\partial_{x}-\mathbf{i}A\left(x\right)$. The phase factor follows from basic integration of the equation of motion $\left(\partial_{x}-\mathbf{i}A\left(x\right)\right)\Psi=0\Rightarrow\Psi=e^{\mathbf{i}\int A\cdot dx}\Psi_{0}$ called a parallel transport equation in this context. What might remain unclear is the origin of the gauge field.